# Calling a service from a callback method in Client

Tags: wcf, client, callback, nested

I have a scenario where, upon receiving a command on one of the callback methods in client, the client needs to call another service.
For example: 
In OnNewCommand() callback method client receives a message X. Now the client must call Service1() defined in the server. Note, Client has registered to the callback of Service1(). I can not use the same client object to call Service1() since it results in dead-lock. So I use a new client object to call Service1(). But it hangs until timeout period expires.
Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same kind of issue (callback hangs until timeout).
I solved this problem by setting an attribute on the object implementing the callback interface:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for this answer, my callback actually gets called-back now :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting a deadlock...

If possible define your callback methods to be “OneWay” and/or make a none blocking call to them, e.g. “begin_m1(...)”

Also check what the ConcurrencyMode you are using on the client and the server and see if you can use ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant or ConcurrencyMode.Muliple

See Chapter 5 of [Programming WCF services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997) for a good discussion of this

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Had to add

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

above my callback class.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, a couple of things to check for:

- If you're using HTTP, increase the number of [HTTP connections allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y.aspx) from the client side to the HTTP server. This is 2 by default and might not be enough for your needs.
- Make sure the [throttling options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx) in your WCF service are enough to handle all your required connections.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your service  has no ConcurencyMode set on it's behavior.

See something like `[ServiceBehavior(ConcurencyMode=ConcurencyMode.Reentrant)]`
or similar attributes (like CallbackBehavior)